# Simon Algorithm without measurement

Tags: density-matrix, simons-algorithm

I want to use the reduced density matrix to compute the measurement probability: $prob(y)=\langle y|\rho|y\rangle$ for a 3-qubit simon algorithm, instead of measuring the ancilla qubits. Here $\rho=Tr_{ancilla}(|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|)$.

I have managed to show that after the circuit, the state is:
$|\psi\rangle=\frac{1}{2^3}\sum_{x\in\{0,1\}^3}(\sum_{y\in\{0,1\}^3}(-1)^{x \cdot y}|y\rangle)\otimes|f(x)\rangle$ but I am not sure how to proceed, meaning how can I "trace-out" the ancilla qubit and be left with a reduced density matrix with which I can calculate probabilities.

Comment: If you have a two-qubit state, do you know how to trace out one qubit, leaving behind a description of the other qubit as a reduced density matrix?

Comment: well yes, if f is given. in this case I am not so sure